# How to get the Log property of DatabaseFacade?

Tags: c#, logging, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

When I googled for "entityframework" and "logging", [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) popped up and several people from here have also mentioned the same article.

However, when I tried it, I can't seem to get the Log property.  What am I missing?

My implementation of the DbContext (btw, this was generated by Entityframework's own scaffolding):

```
internal partial class SharedContext : DbContext
{
    public SharedContext()
    {
    }...
}
```

Here's how I tried to use:
SharedContext context = new();

```
//I am getting CS1061 (DatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for Log....
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
```

Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is tagged with .NET 6 and EF Core while the article refers to EF 6 which is previous iteration of EF for .NET Framework. You should look into [logging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) for EF Core. For example using [simple logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging) via overloading `OnConfiguring` method:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
```

Also probably you should consider setting up context via dependency injection ([DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)):

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SharedContext>(opts => opts // or AddDbContextFactory
      .Use{YourDatabaseType}(...)
      .LogTo(Console.WriteLine));
```

Comment: If it helps, (as a follow on for me from this answer), if you need to log to the debug output of Visual Studio or your IDE, replace the final line above in the dependency injection part from ``` .LogTo(Console.WriteLine) ``` with ``` .LogTo(message => Debug.WriteLine(message)) ``` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#logging-to-the-debug-window